# GSON adding java objects from arraylist to existing json file?

Tags: java, json, arraylist, gson

I have a program that currently can read from JSON file and implement these into a object, and store in a arraylist of objects. I asked a question yesterday about how to write back to the JSON file and someone suggested the .put method however this doesn't write correctly in the JSON format. For example, when there is an existing JSON object as below in the .json file:
 `[
  {
    "waterSpace": 4.0,
    "airSpace": 5.0,
    "landSpace": 3.0,
    "name": "robbie",
    "penType": "pen"
  }
]`
but when I use .put to add it does the following
    `[
  {
    "waterSpace": 4.0,
    "airSpace": 5.0,
    "landSpace": 3.0,
    "name": "robbie",
    "penType": "pen"
  }
]{"waterSpace": 4.0,
    "airSpace": 5.0,
    "landSpace": 3.0,
    "name": "robbie",
    "penType": "pen"
  }`

How can I use GSON to add the objects from the arraylist properly so the formatting is correct and it looks like the below:
`[
  {
    "waterSpace": 4.0,
    "airSpace": 5.0,
    "landSpace": 3.0,
    "name": "robbie",
    "penType": "pen"
  },{
"waterSpace": 4.0,
    "airSpace": 5.0,
    "landSpace": 3.0,
    "name": "robbie",
    "penType": "pen"
  }
]`

Answer (score 0):

GSON has a serializer too, so all you need to use is the fromJson method to convert your object to JSON again.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Deserializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       List<YourObject> yourObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
       YourObject object1 = new YourObject(10.2, 3.7, 8.5, "test", "test");
       YourObject object2 = new YourObject(5.7, 4.9, 3.1, "test2", "test2");
       yourObjectList.add(object1);
       yourObjectList.add(object2);
       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(
            gson.toJson(yourObjectList, new TypeToken<List<YourObject>>() {}.getType()));
       System.out.println(jsonArray);
   }

    public static class YourObject {

       private double waterSpace;
       private double airSpace;
       private double landscape;
       private String name;
       private String penType;

       public YourObject(double waterSpace, double airSpace, double landscape, String name, String penType) {
           this.waterSpace = waterSpace;
           this.airSpace = airSpace;
           this.landscape = landscape;
           this.name = name;
           this.penType = penType;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(this.waterSpace) + " " + String.valueOf(this.airSpace) + " "
                + String.valueOf(this.landscape) + " " + this.name + " " + this.penType;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this looks good however see line where you create the json array, you have the objects in quotation marks but this means I have to manually add the objects. My idea is to do this automatically using a loop, adding objects from an arraylist of animals? Please help

Comment: Edited the answer to create the objects instead of read the JSON. But there is no difference, you will use the same method toJson to serialize the object. In the previous answer, I deserialized the JSON, so the elements in the list was objects too

Answer (score -1):

This is an example implemented into a spring boot project but you can do it in a simple java application or others:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AlfredValidator1Application  implements CommandLineRunner{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AlfredValidator1Application.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    test t1=new test(4.0, 5.0, 3.0, "robbie", "pen");
    test t2=new test(4.0, 5.0, 3.0, "robbie", "pen");
    List<test> listTest=new ArrayList<>();
    listTest.add(t1);
    listTest.add(t2);
    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(listTest));// you can use Gson instead
}
}

class test{
private double waterSpace;
private double airSpace;
private double landSpace;
private String name;
private String penType;

public test(){

}

public test(double waterSpace, double airSpace, double landSpace, String name, String penType) {
    super();
    this.waterSpace = waterSpace;
    this.airSpace = airSpace;
    this.landSpace = landSpace;
    this.name = name;
    this.penType = penType;
}

public double getWaterSpace() {
    return waterSpace;
}

public void setWaterSpace(double waterSpace) {
    this.waterSpace = waterSpace;
}

public double getAirSpace() {
    return airSpace;
}

public void setAirSpace(double airSpace) {
    this.airSpace = airSpace;
}

public double getLandSpace() {
    return landSpace;
}

public void setLandSpace(double landSpace) {
    this.landSpace = landSpace;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPenType() {
    return penType;
}

public void setPenType(String penType) {
    this.penType = penType;
}
```

}

Comment: Downvote for a solution that adds in the use of a giant framework for no good reason.

Comment: @bhspencer I don't want to tell him to use spring boot as framwork but i want juste to give him an example and he can use it without any framework or with other framworks if he want of course so your downvote for me has no sens

Comment: Then consider writing a minimal answer that just shows the OP how to solve the problem.